# How to run constructed commands in julia?

Tags: julia

I am having package names in an array, trying to execute "using <PACKAGE_NAME>" with the following code in deps.jl:

```
#! /opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/bin/Julia
packages =["MbedTLS","HTTP"]
for package in packages
try
("using "package) 
cath err
println("$err")
end
end
```

executing, $/home/julia/deps.jl, throws error "cannot juxtapose string literal".
Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use symbols and `@eval` macro to do this. `@eval` macro runs the given expression at the top level.

```
packages = [:MbedTLS, :HTTP] # use symbols instead of strings
for package in packages
    try
        @eval(using $package) 
    catch err
        println("$err")
    end
end
```

If you need to use strings for some reason, you can first convert it to a `Symbol` and use `@eval` with the results.

```
packages = ["MbedTLS", "HTTP"]
for package in packages
    try
        @eval(using $(Symbol(package))) 
    catch err
        println("$err")
    end
end
```

`"using "package` tries to create the string literal "using" to juxtapose it to variable `package` (i.e. like `5` in `x=3; b = 5x`). String literal juxtaposition [is a syntax error](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/20575) in Julia 1.0. Even if it wasn't a syntax error, I do not recall that it would be used for *running* expressions.

Please see [Metaprogramming section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/) in Julia documentation for more about creating and manipulating code from within Julia.

Comment: It is understood that @eval should be avoided. Any other better approach, please.

Comment: @AVA, could you elaborate on why you should avoid `@eval`?